# Error: missing 1 required positional argument: , 'occurred at index time'

Tags: pandas, mutable

I am trying to write different sheet names in python based on different dataframes that are created from groupby function for two columns.

```
list_dfs=[]
TT=Dataframe.groupby(['change','x2'])
for group,name in TT:
    list_dfs.append(group)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

def dt(_,g): 
    for _,g in Dataframe.groupby (Dataframe.index):
        print (g) 
        _.to_excel(writer,g)
        writer.save()

DT=Dataframe.apply(dt)
```

it keeps giving me this error

```
TypeError: ("dt() missing 1 required positional argument: 'g'", 'occurred at index time')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just a general comment, your convention on variable name looks a bit confusing. I presume that `DataFrame` is a variable whose type is DataFrame? Usually variables of that nature is called <something>df, following the usual variable names in pandas documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
def dt(_,g):
```

takes two arguments.

`DataFrame.apply` takes a function (or lambda) that takes in only one argument (either a `Series` or `ndarray`).

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Try changing the signature of function `dt` to:

```
def dt(g):
```

Answer (score 0):

I just do a small trick as follows.

```
Dataframe['x2']=res
TT=Dataframe.groupby(['change',res])

writer = ExcelWriter('output.xls')

for name,group in TT:
    group.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_{}'.format(name))

writer.save()
```